# Example of Three Polyhedrons in $\mathbb {R^2}$ where any Two Have Non-Empty Intersection, but Empty Intersection Amongst All

Tags: geometry

Suppose we are in $\mathbb R^2$.
It is not true that the polyhedra $P_1, P_2$,...$P_K$ (where $K \geq 3$) in the plane have a point in common if every two of them have a point in common.

For example:
Let $P_1=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x=0\}$, $P_2=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb {R^2} \mid y=0 \}$, $P_3=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb {R^2} \mid y=x-1 \}$

Any two have a point in common but the intersection amongst all three is empty. This is an interesting and cool example.
I was wondering what some other possible examples of polyhedron were to illustrate this fact.

Comment: I am not sure that straight lines are polyhedra.  But almost all sets of three straight lines in the plane have this property

Comment: In 2D, the three edges of a triangle have this property. In 3D, the four faces of a tetrahedron have the property that any *three* have nonempty intersection, but all four have empty intersection. This pattern can be generalized to arbitrarily many dimensions. Of course, one can obtain bounded sets with nonempty interior simply by "thickening" the sets a bit to obtain rectangles in 2D, prisms in 3D, etc.

Comment: I hadn't seen that your example was with boundaries of polygons, not considering their interior. The example of Siong Thye Goh and mine are using **filled** polygons (i.e., their interior with or without their boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you want bounded polygons, it suffices to "bend" in a suitable way the straight lines solution ; for example for $K=3$ :

[image]

This method is suitable in any dimension ; consider for example the case of $K=5$ unbounded regions delimited by $5$ straight lines :

[image]

Their boundaries can be "bended" into closed polygons, giving this solution:

[image]

Comment: No reaction to my answer ?

Comment: A remark on terminology : in $\mathbb{R}^2$ use the term "polygon" and keep the term "polyhedron" exclusively for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $P_1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x \le 0 \}$, $P_2 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y \le 0\}$, $P_3 = \{(x,y): x+y \ge 1 \}$

[image]

Comment: Neat answer, thanks!

Comment: Is a line not a polyhedron, I know a halfspace is a polyhedron, but now I'm confused whether a line is?

Comment: check the definition then? if polyhedron is defined to be intersection of finite halfspaces, then a linear is clearly a polyhedron.

Comment: ah right makes sense, someone commented that they weren't sure that straight lines are polyhedra, but what you said is what i thought